# Node Crypto aes-128-ecb encrypt doesnt get me right results

Tags: python, node.js, openssl, aes

Following program in python:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
key = '11223344556677889900aabbccddeeff'.decode("hex")
aesECB = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
ciphertext = aesECB.encrypt('1234567890abcdef')
print ciphertext.encode('base64')
```

Gets me this result:

```
$ python example_cipher.py 
r9yD3EmmAIpxncxZSldsKg==
```

Following command line from openssl, gets me the same result:

```
$ echo -n "1234567890abcdef" | openssl aes-128-ecb -K 11223344556677889900aabbccddeeff -nopad | openssl base64
r9yD3EmmAIpxncxZSldsKg==
```

But this code in Node:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var key = new Buffer('11223344556677889900aabbccddeeff', 'hex');
var plaintext = new Buffer('1234567890abcdef', 'utf8');
var cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes-128-ecb", key);
cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8');
console.log(ciphertext.toString('base64'));
```

Doesn'g gets me the same result:

```
$ node cipher
tOunZRvle8B6HYuBSzblqw==
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, **DO NOT** use ECB if you are in control of the crypto parameters. It is incredibly insecure and should not be used to encrypt data.

Now for ECB, which technically does not use an IV, you still need to use `crypto.createCipheriv()` with a zero-length IV `Buffer` to match the output of Python:

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, Buffer.alloc(0));
```

Also (in general), you are missing `cipher.final()` to include any leftover data, so use this instead:

```
var ciphertext = Buffer.concat([
  cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8'),
  cipher.final()
]);
```

Comment: It worked, but at first time, it give me an error: buffer.js:93
    throw new TypeError('"value" argument must not be a number');
So I use Buffer.from(''), and now it's going OK !

Comment: That was a typo, I've fixed it now.

Comment: your example code working fine but i have changed key with same length of characters it showing as "invalid key length" error on line : var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, Buffer.alloc(0));

Comment: @Nr. `key` has to be 16 bytes in length for a 128-bit AES key. Make sure `key` is a `Buffer` and that `key.length === 16`.